# Get courses.list without archived classes

Tags: google-classroom

Using a HTTP GET request, how would you only get the classes that are active. Could you add a parameter to the Google API URL that only returns a list of active classes? Or do you have to search through the returned array and delete any classes are archived using a for loop?

```
    var classroom = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    classroom.open('GET',
      'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses');
    classroom.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
      'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    classroom.send();

    classroom.onload = function () {
        if (classroom.readyState === classroom.DONE) {
            if (classroom.status === 200) {
              var response = JSON.parse(classroom.response);
              vm.classes = response.courses;
              console.log(response);
              for (var i = 0; i < response.courses.length; i++){
                var courses = response.courses[i];
                console.log(courses.name);

              }
            } else {
              console.log("Error Unknown");
            }
        }
    };
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no filter option yet like with User objects. (That's documented for at least as far as I can tell). So yes you'll have to pull all of the courses and then just filter out the archived courses. https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses there's a CourseState section that lists the 5 possible states a course can be in. [COURSE_STATE_UNSPECIFIED, ACTIVE, ARCHIVED, PROVISIONED, DECLINED]

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the docs, [courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) returns a list of courses that the requesting user is permitted to view. It does not state a direct way of retrieving active classes only. You may have to resort to your said implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_courses(student) {
  var optionalArgs = {
    studentId: student
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  var active_courses = [];
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      if(course.courseState == "ACTIVE"){

        active_courses.push(course);

        Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }

  return active_courses;
}
```

Comment: the optional Args does not seem to work exactly.  LIST does not seem to accept any args in C#.